# Understanding Theorem $5.1$ in Massey: $H^q(M;\mathbb{Z})$ and $\mathrm{Hom}(H_q(M;\mathbb{Z}),\mathbb{Z}$) are not isomorphic in general

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, abelian-groups

Theorem $5.1$ in Massey p$.366$ is the following:

Let $M$ be a compact oriented $n-$manifold and $F$ a field. Then the bilinear form $$H^q(M;F) \otimes H^{n-q}(M;F) \longmapsto F$$ defined by $$u \otimes v \longmapsto \langle u  \smile v, \mu\rangle$$
is nonsingular.

I do understand the proof but I don't understand the observation made right after it which is the following:

It would be nice to have an analogue of Theorem $5.1$ for the case of cohomology with integer coefficients, rather than coefficient in a field. Since the groups $H^q(M;\mathbb{Z})$ and Hom($H_q(M;\mathbb{Z}),\mathbb{Z}$) are not isomorphic in general some modifications are needed.

I don't understand the latter, shouldn't be the isomorphism a consequence of the fact of universal coefficient Theorem for cohomology since Ext($A,B$) = 0 if either $A$ or $B$ is free? This seems the case taking $G = \mathbb{Z}$.

Any help reference or solution in order to understand the problem would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not at all the case that $\operatorname{Ext}_R^1(A,B)=0$ when $B$ is a free $R$-module. It is the case when $A$ is projective (in particular when it's free), or when $B$ is *injective*. But when $R=\mathbb{Z}$, being injective means being divisible, so it is completely different from being free.

In short, there is no reason that $\operatorname{Ext}_{\mathbb{Z}}^1(A,\mathbb{Z})=0$ unless $A$ has some special property. In fact, $\operatorname{Ext}_{\mathbb{Z}}^1(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z})\simeq \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ for example.